# How can we insert cookies into the MobileFirst request when using the Xamarin WorklightResourceRequestAndroid API?

Tags: c#, android, cookies, xamarin, ibm-mobilefirst

We are working on a MobileFirst project, using the Xamarin SDK to build the client-side code (in this example on Android, although we are looking for a more general solution that covers iOS too) where we are migrating some JavaScript-based adapters to Java. Previously, we were using C# code to call a JavaScript adapter like this, in order to insert cookies into the request (these are to present to ISAM, although that's mostly incidental).

```
var wlClient = WorklightClient.NativeObject as WLClient;
var cookie = new BasicClientCookie(name, value) { Path = path, Domain = domain, };
wlClient.CookieStore.AddCookie(cookie);

var connectResponse = await wlConnect.Connect();    
var invocationData = new WorklightProcedureInvocationData("CP4BackendJavaScript", "cp4Test", new object[0]);    
var responseAsProcedure = await wlClient.InvokeProcedure(invocationData);
```

Given that we are migrating to Java-based adapters, we need to switch to [the ResourceRequest style](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/server-side-development-category/invoking-adapter-procedures-hybrid-client-applications/) of invocation.

However, this doesn't appear to provide us a way of inserting cookies into the request, as the WorklightResourceRequestAndroid object we are using is not linked to the wlClient we were using before:

```
var uri = new Uri(_worklightClient.ServerUrl + "/adapters/CP4BackendJavaScript/cp4Test");
var request = new WorklightResourceRequestAndroid(uri, "GET");
var responseAsResource = await request.Send();
```

How can we insert known cookies into this request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, extending on from Ajay's suggestion, it would appear that the answer is to use the static instance code to insert the cookies:

```
var wlClient = WorklightClient.NativeObject as WLClient;
var cookie = new BasicClientCookie(name, value) { Path = path, Domain = domain, };
wlClient.CookieStore.AddCookie(cookie);
```

We can then create an instance and make a request based upon it, which automatically inserts the cookies:

```
var _worklightClient = WorklightClient.CreateInstance(activity)
var uri = new Uri(_worklightClient.ServerUrl + '/adapters/CP4BackendJavaScript/cp4Test");
var request = _worklightClient.ResourceRequest(uri, "GET");
var responseResource = await request.Send();
```

Answer (score 1):

Connection issue: The `WorklightResourceRequestAndroid` Class is from the underlying  `Worklight.Xamarin.Android` impl. This may or may not be on the connected wlClient object based on how you got it. Ideally you should not have to go to the underlying OS specific providers but stay at the shared namespace `Worklight`. e.g:

`Worklight.WorklightResourceRequest` .

You can get it from the `IWorklightClient.ResourceRequest(..)` . The `IWorklightClient` object is something you should have instantiated in the Android activity class e.g:

`IWorklightClient wlClient=  Worklight.Xamarin.Android.WorklightClient.CreateInstance (this);`

To answer your cookie question : the underlying Android/iOS impl for resource request does not have the cookie methods - hence they are not in the Xamarin layer as well.